# Structural difference between Relational Databases vs. Multidimensional Databases

Tags: sql, data-structures, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I'm trying to develop a deeper understanding of Multidimentional Databases, particularly, the one created by SSAS/MS-SQL. I am not sure how physically a cube's storage is different than that of pages that hold tables.

Please bear in mind that I'm fully knowledgable of how the relationships and purposes of Relational and Multidimensional Relationships differ, conceptually I'm 100% clear. **I am just having difficulty understanding how is the implementation of a Relational Database differs from that of a Multidimensional Database? (particularly physical implementation and data structure differences)**

**Please do not cite conceptual designs such as "Star/Snowflake Schemas" or concepts given here: [Relational vs. Dimensional Databases, what's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798595/relational-vs-dimensional-databases-whats-the-difference)

I'm already familiar with the concepts... Thank you

Comment: Does the information provided by Microsoft sufficient for you:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh916543.aspx?

Comment: At a glance, it seems very conceptual (ie. again, it's great if you want to use the technology but not program it or conduct research on it - but I'll dig through it in more details to see if they get down to the data structures of the cubes)

Comment: There's a difference in abstraction between the API for the developer and trying to read the actual physical files that make up the database.  I recommend that you use the APIs in the [Developer Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500153.aspx).

Comment: not really sufficient. I think you confused his question about the internal workings of a cube with one that explains how to use it